# Css Box model fails:the total width remains at specified value

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I noticed the very strange(for me) behavior in Wordpress.
Let's consider the following simple example. If I set the width to some value, in my example 200px; and specify the border to 1px, the total width of element (ie. content + padding + border) remains 200px.

According to Box Model - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html, if I specify with to 200px, and border to 1px, total width must be 202px(if no paddings are specified). But in Wordpress( tested in version 3.6) it remains 200px. The content becomes 198px, so 198 + 2 = 200

**Example**

```
<div id="test">.</div>

#test {
display:block;
width:200px;
border:1px solid red;
background-color:black;
}
```

If I increase the value of border, for example set it to 4px, the content will become 192px, so total width always remains 200px;

How this can be explained, and how to restore default behavior?

Comment: It's because [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) is being used within `style.css` - the rule is on line 60 if you're using the twentythirteen theme.

Comment: UPPPPS, I did'n know about box-sizing property. I need to set it to content-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meet the [box-sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0).

In your case there's `box-sizing: border-box;` set either to all elements (`*`) or to that particular `div`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about box-sizing. I need to set it to content-box.